# Request async Redux Sauce usando redux-thunk

Tags: react

Boa Tarde pessoal, tudo bem?
Necessito de uma ajuda em relação as actions no [reduxsauce](https://github.com/infinitered/reduxsauce) quando a mesma é um request async. O problema que a action necessita esperar a promise ser resolvida, com isso é necessário usar o [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) para a response gerar uma outra action de sucess. Mas o thunck não funciona com o reduxsauce e com isso fiz um novo middleware se baseado no thunck.

```
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
    return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
            return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
        }else if(typeof action === 'object'){
            action.dispatch = dispatch;
            return next(action);
        }
        return next(action);
    };
}

const thunk = createThunkMiddleware();
thunk.withExtraArgument = createThunkMiddleware;

export default thunk;
```

Com isso resolvi o problema de ter o dispatch na action, mas não consigo chamar lá no redux do sauce uma outra action com o dispatch. Segue minha tentativa e meu Redux completo.

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import HttpClient from '../../../utils/HttpClient'
import {queryString} from '../../../utils/helpers'

//actions
const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
    success: null,
    add: null,
    list: ['endPoint'],
    delete: ['value'],
    edit: ['value']
})

export const GridTypes = Types
export default Creators

//reducers
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    payload: [],
    page: 1,
    pages: 1,
    total: 0,
    orderBy: "",
    direction: "keyboard_arrow_down",
    active: ""
}

export const success = (state,action) => {
    console.log(state,action,":)");
    return state;
}

export const list = (state,action) => {
    let queryStrParams = {
        "page": state.page
    }
    if (state.orderBy !== "") queryStrParams["orderBy"] = state.orderBy;
    let endPoint = `${action.endPoint}?${queryString(queryStrParams)}`;
    return HttpClient.get(endPoint)
        .then(payload => {
            let setState = Object.assign({},state,{
                payload: payload.result,
                total: payload.total,
                pages: payload.pages
            });
            return setState
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}


export const alter = (state,action) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state,action.value);
}

export const add = (state,action) => {
    let errorVal = Object.assign({}, state);
    errorVal.valid = false;
    errorVal.erros.push(action.value);
    return errorVal;
}

export const del = (state,action) => {
    let errorDel = Object.assign({}, state);
    errorDel.erros.splice(action.value, 1);
    errorDel.valid = errorDel.erros.length === 0;
    return errorDel;
}

export const GridReducer = createReducer(
    INITIAL_STATE, {
        [Types.SUCCESS]: success,
        [Types.LIST]: list,
        [Types.EDIT]: alter,
        [Types.ADD]: add,
        [Types.DELETE]: del
    })
```

Preciso chamar o **SUCCESS** no **LIST** após resolver a promise de retorno do backend. tentei assim e não foi.

```
action.dispatch(success()) e action.dispatch(Creators.success())
```

Não tive sucesso! Se poderem me ajudar como se chamar uma outra action dentro do redux agradeço.
Obrigado.